# Thumbnail for Video link shared in WhatsApp from self hosted website using Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, thumbnails, whatsapp, pre-signed-url

I intend to add a thumbnail for the video link that I have shared from a self hosted website. How can I get a thumbnail for the video content that is served using a signed url from Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

```
def get_signed_url(thumbnail):
    blob = bucket.get_blob(thumbnail.path)
    signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration_time)
    logging.info(signed_url)

    return signed_url
```

How should I serve this thumbnail using the html?
Additionally, what will happen if the expiration_time is already met prior to the timestamp that the user has already received the link in Whatsapp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not generate thumbnails for any objects. You would need to generate these thumbnails, upload them to Google Cloud Storage, and then reference them yourself

There are multiples approaches for this, I.e. You can use the [Pillow library](https://python-pillow.org/) for Python to generate your images.

Regarding to the expiration time, your question is unclear to me. The expiration time value is agnostic of the usage of the URL. If you generate an URL for 15 minutes after this time the URL will be rotated and you will need to send a new URL to your user

Answer (score 0):

FFMpeg on Google Cloud Function is supported by default, and using following ffmpeg functions will provideo both a still image (png) and a motion image (webm or gif):

```
ffmpeg.input(video_url, ss=0).filter('scale', png_width, -1).output(out_filesystem_filename, vframes=1).overwrite_output().run()
ffmpeg.input(video_url, ss=0).filter('scale', motion_width, -1).filter('fps', fps=6, round='up').output(out_filesystem_motion_filename, vframes=vframes, loop=0).overwrite_output().run()
```